# Draw rectangle on map - given two opposite coordinates - determine which ones are NE and SW

Tags: javascript, coordinates

How can I determine which coordinates are upper-right (NE) and lower-left (SW) given two points: startPoint(lat1,lon1) and the opposite endPoint(lat2,lat2)? The problem is that this rectangle can be drawn starting from any corner (top-right, top-left, bottom-right, or bottom-left). 
This calculation should be valid anywhere in the globe (below and above the Equator or Prime Meridian, crossing them,  etc...)

(The third corner would be (lat1, lon2) and the fourth corner (lat2, lon1).)
This should be in JavaScript.

```
function getRectangularCoordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
var RectangularCoordinates = new Object();

....

RectangularCoordinates.NE = ...;
RectangularCoordinates.NW = ...;
RectangularCoordinates.SW = ...;
RectangularCoordinates.SE = ...;

return RectangularCoordinates;       }
```

Comment: North and South are easy: whichever is largest is North (South Pole = -90, North Pole = +90)

Comment: You could use the same algorithm for West-East (-180 to +180), but that would be problematic across the dateline (e.g. +179 to -170).

Comment: See this image: http://i.piskvor.org/test/which.png It seems very easy: "top left is top left, bottom right is bottom right, no problem." But there is no way to tell if you want *this* rectangle, or the opposite one: http://i.piskvor.org/test/which2.png - same zoom level...

Comment: So, unless your rectangle is rather small in the east-west direction (compared to Earth), there is no way to tell which of the two possible edges is "left" and which is "right".

Comment: What if I calculate the center first, height and width based on the given two opposite coordinates... Would having that additional information help in any way?

Comment: Well, *which* center? Given the two points in my example, how do you pick if the center is in the middle of image #1, or in the middle of #2? Note that the red and blue marker are in the same position in both images.

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be to allow on drawing a rectangle only from NE to SW point. (I would like to see any suggestions on that as well). Unless anyone here has a better idea.

Comment: So "the corner which is northernmost is always the easternmost"? That would work, yeah.